# Can I ignore some folder (containing bazel configuration) while building the project recursively?

Tags: bazel

For some reasons, practical or not, rxjs npm package stores BAZEL.build configuration in the package, so when I'm trying to build my project (which has node_modules folder) bazel tries automatically to build something that it's not supposed to build at all.

My question would be - what is canonical way of ignoring some specific folder while building bazel project recursively?

The only way to achieve what I'm looking for that I know of is to point to it explicitly in the command line

`bazel build //...  --deleted_packages=node_modules/rxjs/src` (see [user manual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html))

But I don't want to type this every time.

Comment: What is the command you are using to "build your project"? bazel build //... ?

Comment: @Adam precisely - it's a project with a lot of subprojects so listing all them is technically doable but practically impossible

Comment: Issue is tracked here https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4888

Comment: `deleted_packages ` this option is no longer in the document

Answer (score 12):

Bazel recently added a feature for ignoring folders (similar to gitignore).

Simply add `node_modules` to the `.bazelignore` file in the root of your project.

Comment: How to exclude a dir which is inside `new_local_repository`? Simply pointing it to this dir does not seem to work.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is expressible as a bazel target pattern:

```
bazel build -- //... -//node_modules/rxjs/src/...
```

Full documentation is available at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#target-patterns

Comment: is there's any way to put this into config so that I won't be needed to type it every time?

Comment: I don't know of a way.

Comment: Actually, it seems that if you put "build -- -//node_modules/rxjs/src/..." in tools/bazel.rc, then this may work. However, I think it's a hack that should not work. And it also breaks the "bazel info" and "bazel clean" commands

Comment: well, that's a shame actually, but thank you for answering.